# loop inside <select> with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know why this code doesn't work:

```
$("body").append("<select>");

    for (j in boxes[i].ex_options ){

       $("body").append("<option>"+boxes[i].ex_options[j]+"</option>");

                    }

$("body").append("</select>");
```

`<select>` items are not correctly displayed.

They're asking for this, just in case:

```
var Box = function (ex_solution, ex_img, ex_options) {

    this.ex_solution    = ex_solution;
    this.ex_img         = ex_img;
    this.ex_options     = ex_options;

}

var boxes = [];

boxes.push(new Box ("solution1","images/caja1>",["solution 1.1", "option 1.2", "option 1.3"]));
```

Thank you

Comment: `append()` is not a string concatenate function

Comment: I'm so sorry, bucle is not an english word, I meant a loop.

Arun P Johny, what should i use instead? Cause append() usually works for adding html code.

Answer (score 2):

`append()`, as @ArunPJohny points out, doesn’t concatenate strings; it appends DOM elements. When you add your first `<select>`, it creates a `<select>` element, then adds a bunch of `<option>`s outside of it. What you can do is create an element and pass an array of `<option>`s to `append()`, like this:

```
$("body").append(
    $("<select>").append(
        $.map(boxes[i].ex_options, function(option) {
            return $("<option>").text(option);
        })
    )
);
```

Comment: When I try this code I get this error: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist. If I understand, this is creating a <select></select> and introducing the content of boxes[i].ex_options inside surrounded by <option></option>, isn't?

What I don't understand then is why this works and select doesn't: 

    $("body").append("<p>"+boxes[i].ex_solution+"</p>");

    $("body").append("<img src='"+boxes[i].ex_img+"'/>");

Thank you for the help

Comment: @pboest: I tried to explain it in the second sentence – pretty much, the first `append()` automatically closes the `<select>`, if you want to think of it like that. As for that error… could you make a jsFiddle/CodePen, please?

Comment: Maybe I'm implementing it wrong, I tried.. thank you for your help:

http://codepen.io/pboest/pen/EDLaI

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://brenda.upreach.org.uk/plugins/jquery.datepick.package-4.1.0/redmond.datepick.css"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://brenda.upreach.org.uk/plugins/jquery.datepick.package-4.1.0/jquery.datepick.js">  </script>


    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.datepick').datepick({ 
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy', showTrigger: '#calImg'});
    });


    $(document).ready(function(){

        var Box = function (ex_solution, ex_img, ex_options) {
            this.ex_solution    = ex_solution;
            this.ex_img         = ex_img;
            this.ex_options     = ex_options;
        }

        var boxes = [];
        boxes.push(new Box ("solution1","images/caja1>",["solution 1.1", "option 1.2", "option 1.3"]));

        $("body").append("<select></select>");
        $.each(boxes[0].ex_options, function(index, value){
            console.debug(value);
            $("body select").append("<option>"+value+"</option>");
        });

    });
    </script>

    <body></body>
```

Comment: That’s really inefficient and won’t work that well if there’s any other `<select>` on the page…

Comment: True. I wasn't going for efficiency. Just trying to illustrate where his/her code went wrong with as few changes to the original as possible. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Maybe as @minitech said, when I try this it adds every option to every select box, resulting in a first select box with every option else. The only good one is the last created.